# Can't launch StarStable through Wine on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, launcher, games, 32-bit

I've recently switched to Linux and I'm trying to install a launcher for an online game called Star Stable. I was following instructions on [this site](http://erik.torgesta.com/2015/11/how-to-play-star-stable-on-linux/). Everything works fine till I launch the game launcher and log myself in.

A window appears, saying "The StarStableLauncher.exe has experienced a serious error" or something to that effect. Then the game window becomes darker and gets closed and the debugging option from Wine appears instead.

So I've looked in the logfile and this is what the highlighted line says:

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address (nil) (thread 0009), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00000000).
err:dbghelp:pe_load_msc_debug_info -Debug info stripped, but no .DBG file in module L"xul"
```

There are also few lines at the beginning of the logfile that could be helpful:

```
[12/12/16 18:23:20] - Running wine-1.9.24 winecfg (Working directory : /home/tanja/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/SSO)
[12/12/16 18:23:39] - Running wine-1.9.24 /home/tanja/Downloads/StarStableOnlineSetup.exe (Working directory : /)
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0x33eca0,-1,(nil),(nil),6,2,(nil),8192,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts poorly handled shortcut format, advertised shortcut
fixme:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts poorly handled shortcut format, advertised shortcut
err:msi:MsiEnableLogW Unable to enable log L"" (3)
```

Other errors that I've noticed:

```
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:urlmon:InternetBindInfo_GetBindString not supported string type 20
```

---

```
fixme:msctf:ThreadMgrSource_AdviseSink (0x1a639c8) Unhandled Sink: {71c6e74e-0f28-11d8-a82a-00065b84435c}
9[5e716e0]: TSF: 0x8b45260 TSFStaticSink::Init() FAILED to install ITfInputProcessorProfileActivationSink (0x80004001)
9[5e716e0]: TSF:   TSFTextStore::Initialize() FAILED to initialize TSFStaticSink instance
```

---

```
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
```

---

```
fixme:mshtml:process_meta_element Unsupported document mode L"IE=edge"


System information:
Wine build: wine-1.9.24
Platform: i386
Version: Windows 7
Host system: Linux
Host version: 4.4.0-53-generic
```

- System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
- Memory: 7.7 GiB,
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4,
- Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile,
- OS-Type: 64-bit,
- Disk: 243,6 GB

I will be thankful for any help or tips. :)